# How to position a Label horizontally in Windows Forms code-behind

Tags: c#, winforms, label, alignment

I have a Windows form that I want to manipulate from code-behind.In other words:

I can do stuff like this:

```
myForm.TheLableThatIWantToPosition.Text = "Some text!";

myForm.TheLableThatIWantToPosition.ForeColor = Color.Red;

etc.
```

But, how can I position it horizotnally ? I want to center it horizontally.

I tried with the:

```
myForm.TheLableThatIWantToPosition.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

and all the other options but it just doesn't happen.

Comment: what do you mean by positioning a label horizontally ? can you explain it more clearly ?

Comment: You want to align label's text or label itself?

Comment: Well, I have a Label that dynamically changes its .Text and according to the text length it doesn't get aligned horizontally in the center but it just starts from the same point and decreases according to the length of the text.

Comment: King's answer down should do the trick

Comment: You probably just forgot to set the label's AutoSize property to false.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik it looks like that you want its content to be `centered` not the whole `Label`? if so, what do you want it to be centered on? (the `Label Bounds` or `Label's Parent Bounds`)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center align content in label -

```
AutoSize = false;
TextAlign = MiddleCenter;
```

Comment: Yes.  And set the Size.

Answer (score 1):

You can place this code in a `SizeChanged` event handler of your `label1.Parent`:

```
if(label1.Parent != null){ //this if check may be removed if it's sure that Parent is not null
 label1.Left = (label1.Parent.Width - label1.Width)/2;
}
```

Better you should do something like this:

```
//SizeChanged event handler for your label1
private void label1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   label1.Left = (label1.Parent.Width - label1.Width)/2;
}
//SizeChanged event handler for your label1's Parent
private void parent_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   label1.Left = (label1.Parent.Width - label1.Width)/2;
}
//you can change label1.Parent with a control reference which you know it's the container of your label1.
```

To make it dynamically, for example you have a class `CustomLabel` and you want it to be centered by default whenever it's placed/added to another container:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label {
  public CustomLabel(){
     IsCentered = true;
  }
  private Control oldParent;
  public bool IsCentered {get;set;}//You can define an Enum if needed
  protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e){
    if(Parent != null&&IsCentered){
       Center();
    }
  }
  protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e){
     if(Parent != null){
        if(oldParent != null) oldParent.SizedChanged -= parent_SizeChanged;
        Parent.SizedChanged -= parent_SizeChanged;
        Parent.SizedChanged += parent_SizeChanged;
        Center();
     }
     oldParent = Parent;
  }
  private void parent_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(IsCentered) Center();
  }
  public void Center(){
    Left = (Parent.Width - Width)/2;
  }
}
```

Comment: this code won't work correctly because the when TextChanged is fired the actual text of the label is not changed so the label1.Left will be calculated according to the old label1.width

Comment: @Dima My code doesn't care about `TextChanged`, it cares about `SizeChanged`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I kind of saw TextChanged there.

Comment: When changing parent this code will react for both parent's events(I mean old parent and new parent)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you're right, however it's always centered in the current parent. Although if the old parent is resized, there is some `redundant` execution.

Comment: Nope. your code will result in `NullReferenceException` when you set parent to null. Isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel no, I've checked `Parent!=null` before centering it, I updated code so that the problem of `old parent and new parent` has not been there.